# How can one control Quodlibet through media keys?

Tags: keys, quodlibet, media

The last time I used Quodlibet I found out that one had to enable 2 plugins for the media keys to work with it. One had something to do with  DBus and the other one with an MPRIS thing.

I enabled both plugins now that I have begun to use it again, but media keys still won't work, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in 2.3.2. Use the PPA for the latest version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lazka/ppa
```

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: Seems to have worked for now! Will mark as answer after it proves to be a permanent solution.